# Animation border - Windows Store App

Tags: xaml, windows-runtime, windows-store-apps

I have the following XML that i use to change the background of selected items in a ListBox

```
<Style x:Key="ItemStyle" TargetType="ListBoxItem">
    <Setter Property="Height" Value="60" />
    <Setter Property="Width" Value="60" />
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="ListBoxItem">
                <Grid Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                    <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="SelectionStates" >
                            <VisualState x:Name="Unselected" />
                            <VisualState x:Name="Selected">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <ColorAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="fillColor" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Rectangle.Fill).(SolidColorBrush.Color)" BeginTime="00:00:00" Duration="0" To="{StaticResource AccentColor}" />
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                            <VisualState x:Name="SelectedUnfocused">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <ColorAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="fillColor" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Rectangle.Fill).(SolidColorBrush.Color)" BeginTime="00:00:00" Duration="0"  To="{StaticResource AccentColor}" />
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                            <VisualState x:Name="SelectedPressed">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <ColorAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="fillColor" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Rectangle.Fill).(SolidColorBrush.Color)" BeginTime="00:00:00" Duration="0"  To="{StaticResource AccentColor}" />
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                            <VisualState x:Name="SelectedPointerOver">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <ColorAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="fillColor" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Rectangle.Fill).(SolidColorBrush.Color)" BeginTime="00:00:00" Duration="0"  To="{StaticResource AccentColor}" />
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                        </VisualStateGroup>
                    </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                    <Rectangle x:Name="fillColor" IsHitTestVisible="False"  Margin="5"
                               Width="{Binding Width, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"
                               Height="{Binding Height, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" />
                    <ContentPresenter Content="{Binding}" />
                </Grid>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

i want to do the same but using a border 
besides changing the Rectangle to Border, what should i use in the TargetProperty instead of

```
(Rectangle.Fill).(SolidColorBrush.Color)
```

i tried with (Border.BorderBrush).(SolidColorBrush.Color) , but doesnt seem to be working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should use (Border.Background).(SolidColorBrush.Color)

**Edit:**

```
<Style x:Key="ItemStyle" TargetType="ListBoxItem">
    <Setter Property="Height" Value="60" />
    <Setter Property="Width" Value="60" />
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White" />
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="ListBoxItem">
                <Grid Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                    <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="SelectionStates" >
                            <VisualState x:Name="Unselected" />
                            <VisualState x:Name="Selected">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <ColorAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="fillColor" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Border.BorderBrush).(SolidColorBrush.Color)" BeginTime="00:00:00" Duration="00:00:03" To="Azure" />
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                            <VisualState x:Name="SelectedUnfocused">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <ColorAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="fillColor" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Border.BorderBrush).(SolidColorBrush.Color)" BeginTime="00:00:00" Duration="0"  To="Azure" />
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                            <VisualState x:Name="SelectedPressed">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <ColorAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="fillColor" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Border.BorderBrush).(SolidColorBrush.Color)" BeginTime="00:00:00" Duration="0"  To="Azure" />
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                            <VisualState x:Name="SelectedPointerOver">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <ColorAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="fillColor" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Border.BorderBrush).(SolidColorBrush.Color)" BeginTime="00:00:00" Duration="0"  To="Azure" />
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                        </VisualStateGroup>
                    </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                    <Border x:Name="fillColor" IsHitTestVisible="False"  
                       Width="{Binding Width, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"
                       Height="{Binding Height, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" BorderBrush="Green" BorderThickness="4"/>
                    <ContentPresenter Content="{Binding}" />
                </Grid>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Comment: if i use a Border.Background i get this result http://oi60.tinypic.com/z76md.jpg  what i want is just a border line around my image square

Comment: Ah ok, you said you wanted to change the background.. anyway, what kind of problem do you get from (Border.BorderBrush).(SolidColorBrush.Color)? I just tested it and it works fine (using your style), you just have to encrease the BorderBrushThickness and remove the Margin=5 otherwise is not visible